# can we pass arrays as arguments to functions by this syntax, under upcoming c++0x standards?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, syntax, c++11

suppose we have following function:

```
void someFunction(int * araye){
 for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
  cout <<araye[i]<<' ';
 cout <<'\n';
}
```

can we pass an array to this function by following syntax, under upcoming c++0x standards? :

```
someFunction({1,2,3,4,5});
```

if that's true, will we even be able to use this syntax in any case in which, array elements are from POD types like below :

```
class Test{
 int adad1;
 int adad2;
};
void someFunction(Test * araye){
 for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
  cout <<araye[i].adad1<<'-'<<araye[i].adad2<<' ';
 cout <<'\n';
}
someFunction({{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}});
```

**Edit->after what people said:**
So you guys are telling that the expression between braces will be basically treated as an initializer_list and are proposing using an extra function that pulls a pointer out of that initializer_list and passes it to the intended function, but this method seems to me like a hack to be able to use my intended function with that expression as an argument, with that said I think I shouldn't use that expression as an argument at all, when my intended function parameter is a single pointer, or there might be another approach to use that expression? .

Comment: That would be sweet, to treat `int` arrays like `char` arrays have been forever...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function takes `const int*`, rather than `int*`, then you just need a small trampoline function to pull the pointer out of the `std::initializer_list<int>` that the brace initialiser produces. Something like this (probably; I don't have a C++0x compiler to test with)

```
void someFunction(const int * array){
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        std::cout << array[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void someFunction(const std::initializer_list<int>& init) {
    someFunction(init.begin());
}

someFunction({1,2,3,4,5});
```

If your function needs to know the end or size of the array (which will usually be the case), then pass either `init.end()` or `init.size()` as a second argument.

Comment: Compiles and runs as expected with g++ 4.4.4, after changing `initializer` to `initializer_list`

Answer (score 5):

The type of the expression `{1,2,3,4,5}` is `std::initializer_list<int>`. It's an object which has member functions `size()`, `begin()`, `end()`, but no `operator[]` (per `18.9/1` of the C++0x FCD)

If your function took std::vector or any other standard container, this would work because containers can be constructed from initializer_lists (they all provide non-explicit constructors that take them):

```
void someFunction(std::vector<int> araye)
{
         for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
                   std::cout << araye[i] <<' ';
         std::cout <<'\n';
}
int main()
{
        someFunction({1,2,3,4,5});
}
```

If you want to have a function that takes a pointer, you will need to somehow manually convert an initializer_list into something that you can access in such manner:

```
void someFunction(int* araye)
{
         for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
                   std::cout << araye[i] <<' ';
         std::cout <<'\n';
}
void someFunction(std::vector<int> v)
{
        someFunction(&v[0]);
}
int main()
{
        someFunction({1,2,3,4,5});
}
```

Comment: It could be more efficient if you `move` the `initializer_list`.

Comment: @Jon: Can you expand on this?

Comment: @sbi: Never mind, see comments on @David's answer. You can just write `someFunction(std::initializer_list<int> v) { someFunction(v.begin()); }` instead, which avoids copying the `initializer_list` into the `vector`.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Good point. I tried it initially, but without `const` it did not compile and I didn't give it a thought.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Initializer_lists) would seem to suggest that you can do this but only by declaring the function to take a `std::initializer_list<int>` as an argument.

Comment: @Pooria: Depending on implementation, it may or may not be. An implementation is free to treat `initializer_list<T>` basically however it pleases, within the confines of standards compliance. It might just be an array in the static data area, and the `begin()` method might just return a `const T*`.

Comment: @Jon: according to the C++0x draft standard, `begin()` *does* just return a `const T*`.

Comment: @Mike: Well, there you go. See comment on @Cubbi's answer.