# How can i use member initialization list to initialize an array?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
class A {
public:
   A();

private:
   char a[5];
   int* ptr;
};

A::A() : a(0), ptr(0) { }
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The only sensible thing you can do with a C-array in C++03 is value-initialize it (in C++11 and beyond it can be list-initialized).

From the C++03 standard, §8.5/7:

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.

And from §8.5/5:

> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a class type with a user-declared constructor, then the default constructor for `T` is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if `T` has no accessible default constructor);
> - if `T` is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of `T` is value-initialized;
> - **if `T` is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;**
> - **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized**
>
> To *zero-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - **if `T` is a scalar type, the object is set to the value of `0` (zero) converted to `T`;**
> - if `T` is a non-union class type, each nonstatic data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized;
> - if `T` is a union type, the object’s first named data member) is zero-initialized;
> - if `T` is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
> - if `T` is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

So, if your constructor definition is changed to

```
A::A() : a(), ptr() { }
```

then you are guaranteed that post-construction, all 5 elements of `A::a` will have the value `'\0'` and `A::ptr` will be null.

Answer (score 3):

Afraid not; C++ doesn't support initialising arrays like this.

You'll just have to assign to its members in `A`'s constructor body, or you can use *value-initialisation* if you don't really care what the values are:

```
struct A {
   int x[5];
   A() : x();
};
```

C++0x does let you give all the values, though:

```
struct A {
   int x[5];
   A() : x{1,2,3,4,5} {}
};
```

Note, though, that because arrays are not `class-object`s, you won't be able to do this:

```
struct A {
   int x[5];
   A(std::initializer_list<int[5]>& i) // or whatever the T should be
      : x{i} // or x(i)
        {}
}
A a({1,2,3,4,5)};
```

Comment: Wait, not in C++0x either? D:

Comment: Well, in C++0x it is understood (I hope!) that you should always use `std::array<>` over C-arrays, which can be sensibly and cheaply initialized and returned from a static member function for use in c'tor initialization lists.

Comment: @GMan: Indeed. You can't initialise an array with an `std::initializer_list<>`, because arrays have no constructors. You still end up iterating through _something_ in the constructor body of the enclosing type. The reason that this is not really a problem is what ildjarn said.

Comment: g++ 4.5.2 has no problem with `A() : a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} { }` (That doesn't necessarily mean that it's allowed in C++0x, of course.)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Now that you mention it, it may be that I was originally thinking of the `std::initializer_list<>` case by accident; basic element-wise initialisation should indeed be valid, shouldn't it?

Comment: I'll be honest:  I know practically nothing about initializer lists since Visual C++ doesn't support them.

Comment: `std::array<>` is an aggregate. It has no constructors beyond default/copy and (potentially) move (and therefor also no initializer-list constructor). Note that you *could* write a constructor like `template<typename ...T> A(T... t):x{t...} { }` and then write `A a{1, 2, 3}`, but this looks like it would create lots of little template instantiations. Not sure about the code bloat it causes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118025/brace-enclosed-initializer-list-constructor/4118050#4118050