# Initializing an array in constructor.

Tags: c++, arrays, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i use member initialization list to initialize it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602030/how-can-i-use-member-initialization-list-to-initialize-it)

I am trying to initialize an array in my constructor and storing it in my char board[]. I am not sure how I can do this. I just want to initialize the value for board so i can replace it later.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i use member initialization list to initialize it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5602030/636019)

Comment: Why are you not using `std::vector`?

Comment: Or, since the size is known at compile-time, `std::array`/`std::tr1::array`/`boost::array`?

Answer (score 3):

```
  TicTacToe::TicTacToe() : board() { }
```

You should read up on a little more C++ and a good place would be the article linked in the comment on your question.

Comment: Ironic. [Did you even try to compile that?](http://ideone.com/Hvb73) Maybe you should read up on a little more C++. ;-]

Comment: whoops, my bad on the zero, but still...

Answer (score 0):

I had heard that C++ did not support colon-init lists for arrays until just recently, I think.

```
TicTacToe() : board()
{ }
```

This should work, like squinlan said. If not, you can always just assign whatever values you are trying to initialize the board to within the constructor.

Comment: Why repeat what has already been said?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with array of char you could add the constructor:

```
    void TicTacToe() {memset (board, 0, 9);}//this is new
```

to your class definition

```
class TicTacToe {
public:
    void displayBoard();
    void getMove();
    void playGame();

    TicTacToe() {memset (board, 0, 9);}//this is new

private:
    char board[9];
    char player; // Switch after each move.
};
```