# C++ std::map Intristic Type Initialization Using [] Operator

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

What a title, suppose I have a map like this:

```
std::map<int, int> m;
```

and if I write the following

```
cout<<m[4];
```

- What will be the result (0, uninitialized, compiler specific)?
- Does the same applies for pointers (i.e. std::map)?

**EDIT:**
To clarify, in this question I am seeking for standard behavior.

Thanks in advance,
Cem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value will be what the default constructor for the type creates, because new spots are filled using `T()`. For `int`, this is `0`. You can see this for yourself:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << int() << endl; // prints 0
}
```

Initializing a type like with empty parentheses like this is called *value initialization* (see ildjarn's comment below).

Comment: Pedantically, this is called _value-initialization_.

Comment: @ildjarn which part, exactly, is called that?

Comment: @Cem the default value would still be `0`.

Comment: @Seth : Initializing a type with an empty set of parenthesis. The concept is defined in §8.5; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602030/how-can-i-use-member-initialization-list-to-initialize-it/5602057#5602057) for the standardese.

Comment: I know about int(). Its a little bit confusing int x does not do the initialization. If the implementation uses T_ x; and uses x, well you know what will happen. I prefer in terms of standards since I dont have access to ISO C++ standards document.

Comment: @Cem well, that other answer pretty much says it all. _To value-initialize an object of type T means: ...(class types)... otherwise, the object is zero-initialized_. Also, implementations don't use `T_ x;`, they insert `T_()`, which is value-initializing a new object.