# Initializing constant array of fixed size inside class

Tags: c++, c++03

Consider the following class:

```
class A {
    const int arr[2];
public:
      A() { }
};
```

Is it possible to initialize `arr` from the constructor initializer list or in any other way than on the line where it is declared (i.e. `const int arr[2] = {1,2};`)?

Note that I'm interested in methods that work with C++98!

Comment: It's started! Explicit non-C++11-ness in questions. (Nothing wrong with that)

Comment: This is a famous deficiency of C++98, which is why we now have C++11!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Great! Now let's rename `C++` to `C++98/03` and migrate all those tags :-)

Comment: Whats this silliness? Please make this tag be c++03 ... or do we want a cc++ tag or maybe a c#java tag?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I didn't realize there was no slash :-( Please feel free to modify/fix/delete as you see fit. `C++-obsolete` might be the most universal name.

Comment: I've changed the C++-9803 tag to c++98, as that's the specific version that was requested.  I support having c++98, c++03 etc tags, but lumping every old version together into one tag is brokenness waiting to happen.  What happens when C++2x comes out, and c++-obsolete now *includes* c++11?

Comment: [Well covered in the FAQ.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4984228#4984228)

Comment: C++03 was just a technical correction of C++098, the Technical Corrigendum 1 (or TC1 for short). Apart from value initialization it introduced nothing new. So talking about that standard, C++98 is a good designator, in my humble opinion.

Comment: @Alf : Well, value-initialization seems closely tied to this question to me, so the distinction in this case may still be warranted.

Comment: @Alf C++03 is not a TC, but is a new version. Initially they wanted it to be a TC, but eventually it didn't become one.

Comment: @Alf & everyone else: actually I just meant *not* C++11, since that doesn't yet have very good compiler support (in the compilers installed on the servers where I can run my simulation: I'm not free to choose my compiler version).

Comment: @Johannes: C++03 is sold as the C++ standard "incorporating TC1". In its own words it is a "technically revised" edition of C++98. It was not a separate version: nothing new (except value initialization, which is debatable as to newness) was introduced. In contrast, C++11 is a new version. Lots of new things have been introduced, presumably some things have been deprecated, and at least one earlier deprecated thing (implicit conversion of literal to pointer to non-const) has been removed. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By wrapping them in a `struct`, e.g.:

```
class A
{
    struct Data
    {
        int arr[2];
    };

    Data const arr;
public:
    A() : arr( someOtherStruct ) {}
};
```

This does mean that to access the data, you'd have to write `arr.arr`.
It's possible to avoid that by inheriting from the `struct`:

```
struct PrivateDataForA
{
    int arr[2];
};

class A : private PrivateDataForA
{
public:
    A() : PrivateDataForA( someOtherStruct ) {}
};
```

This does make the name of the `struct` visible outside of the class
(which might be an advantage—client code could pass you one as an
argument).

If you don't have an instance of the struct handy, say because you want
to fill it with values calculated from arguments to the constructor, you
can use a static member function:

```
class A : private PrivateDataForA
{
    static PrivateDataForA createInitializer( int a, int b );
public:
    A( int a, int b ) : PrivateDataForA( createInitializer( a, b ) )
    {
    }
};
```

---

For the OP’s concrete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef ptrdiff_t   Size;
typedef Size        Index;

template< class Element, Size n >
struct Array{ Element elem[n]; };

class A {
    Array<int, 2> const arr_;       // const int arr[2];

    A& operator=( A const& );       // No such.

    static Array<int, 2> const& oneAndTwo()
    {
        static Array<int, 2> const a = {1, 2};
        return a;
    }

public:
    A(): arr_( oneAndTwo() ) {}
    int at( Index i ) const { return arr_.elem[i]; }
};


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    A o;
    for( int i = 0;  i < 2;  ++i )
    {
        cout << o.at( i ) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Essentially you're advocating use of `boost::array<>`/`std::tr1::array<>` -- why not say that directly?

Comment: @ildjarn Because I wasn't.  I'm not actually that familiar with either of those classes, and wrapping data in a `struct` is a useful technique to know in general (although only really necessary when C-style arrays are being used).

Comment: Well given that `std::array<>` is now _standard_, it's a good thing to be familiar with. ;-] (And again, it's exactly what your answer is describing.)

Answer (score 2):

Initializing array elements to non-zero values requires C++11 support.

In C++03, it's only possible to value-initialize your array, resulting in each element's value being `0`:

```
class A {
    const int arr[2];
public:
    A() : arr() { }
};
```

For the relevant C++03 standardese, see this question and answer:
[How can i use member initialization list to initialize it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5602030/636019)

<sup>(I'm going to assume that by C++98 you mean *not* C++11, i.e. that C++03 is acceptable. If this assumption is wrong, please say so.)</sup>

Comment: -1: OP specifically gave non-zero values as an example, and non-C++11 as a requirement.

Comment: @Tomalak : I mentioned the only thing that _is_ possible to do, which obviously also indicates what _isn't_ possible to do (everything that wasn't mentioned). Don't be petty. And to be clear, the concrete question is "*Is it possible to initialize `arr` from the constructor initializer list or in any other way than on the line where it is declared?*" OP's example aside, I directly answer that question.

Comment: Don't call me petty. If the OP used non-zero element values as his example, it's pretty clear that that's what he wants. You're just conveniently ignoring half the question.

Comment: No, you're absolutely being petty. A direct question was asked, a direct answer was given. Just because the OP's example isn't satisfiable doesn't mean the question wasn't answered accurately.

Comment: Nonsense, and I shan't argue about it any more. There is really no need for you to get personal just because somebody downvoted your answer.

Comment: I'm not getting personal, but when someone asks "here's what I want to do, is it possible?" and the answer is "here's the only thing that's possible that remotely resembles what you're asking for", if you can't see the obvious answer to the question in that response then that's simply a massive logic failure on your part. /shrug

Comment: Calling me "petty" is personal.

Comment: _petty (adj.): (of behavior) Characterized by an undue concern for trivial matters_ Sounds like an accurate observation to me.

Comment: I never said it wasn't accurate. I said it was personal.

Comment: @Tomalak and also the `{1,2}` was from a *counter* example of how to *not* do it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: That no less defines what "it" is.

Answer (score -2):

No. It's not.

Comment: You're *not* getting an upvote for that. Sometimes being right is not enough :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think you'll find that this is as correct and accurate and useful as any C++98 answer is going to get!

Comment: C++98 did already allow the array() syntax explained in the other answer. it just wasn't called value initialization. so as the question is posed, the answer should be "yes it is possible"

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb But not usefully:-).  (Why would you want an array whose values can only be `0`?)  Other solutions _are_ possible, however; the flat statement that it's not possible is wrong, at least from a practical point of view.  (Technically, you use a `struct`, rather than an array, but if all the `struct` contains is the array, it comes out to the same thing.)

Comment: @james i agree and if i wouldnt.be.in a train on a.phone i would.already have posted that :-X

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: The OP specifically gave the example of `{1,2}`. No solution to do this has been proposed.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal My solution using a `struct` works fine for this; all you have to do is define a static instance of the `struct`, initialized with `{ 1, 2 }`.