# How to implement this recursive function to change the value of any nodes?

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures

I decided to write [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77259975/python-interpreter-doesnt-recognize-function) program in C because I am more familiar with it. In fact I downloaded Visual Studio and I am compiling C with a C++ compiler but its fine.

I have this header file

```
typedef struct Nody Node;

struct Nody
{
     float value;
     float bias;
     Node* rightChild;
     Node* leftChild;
     Node* parent;
};

void initialize(Node* node, Node* rightChild,Node*leftChild,Node*parent);
void changeValue(Node* node, float newval);
void changeBias(Node* node, float bias);
void printinfo(Node node);
void resetNode(Node* node);
void correctBiases(Node** node,float error);
```

and this source file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Node.h"

void initialize(Node* node, Node *rightChild,Node *leftChild,Node *parent)
{
    node->value = 0;
    node->bias = 0.5;
    node->rightChild = rightChild;
    node->leftChild = leftChild;
    node->parent = parent;
}


void changeValue(Node* node, float newval)
{
    node->value = newval;
    node->parent->value += (node->value * node->bias);
}

void changeBias(Node* node, float bias)
{
    node->bias += bias;
}

void printinfo(Node node)
{
    printf("Value:%f Bias:%f \n", node.value, node.bias);
}

void resetNode(Node* node) 
{
    node->value = 0;
}

void correctBiases(Node* node,float error) 
{
}
```

I am trying to write down the `correctBiases()` function.I have created a tree which  is bidirectionally accessible(we can start from a leaf and head to the root).The `correctBiases()` function starts from the root and finds every leaf and changes one of its properties(the bias).

Since the rightChild and the leftChild is a pointer of type Node , I need a double pointer to access  its content , however if I do that I cant start the recursion since I cannot create the recursion step.So I am stuck.What should I do?

Comment: Aside: "C++ compiler is fine" – for C++ code. If you are writing C use a C compiler.

Comment: @WeatherVane its really not bad.C is a subset of C++.It can still compile C source files.

Comment: No, C is not a subset of C++. It is a quite distinct language with similar code but with different rules. C++ can compile C-like source code, but applies the C++ standard, not the C standard.

Comment: @Cerise  [Incompatibilities between ISO C and ISO C++](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm) --  Use a C++ compiler for C++ code, and a C compiler for C code.

Comment: Hmm ok sue Visual Studio for not having a C extension.I am NOT going to waste my time (or hard disk memory) to download 2 different IDEs.A C++ can compile C source code.

Comment: @Cerise What do you mean you can't start the recursion step? You're on the right track with double pointers... I would suggest doing you "tree-recursion-boilerplate" first. Implement some type of logic e.g. `(*node)->bias += error;` and the do your right and left recursion step.

Comment: @WeatherVane "No, C is not a subset of C++. It is a quite distinct language with similar code but with different rules. C++ can compile C-like source code, but applies the C++ standard, not the C standard."Yes thats why C++ has many exactly same libraries with C and it CAN understand C code.How is that not a subset?

Comment: The function signature of the (incomplete) definition does not match the function prototype... Jus' sayin'...

Comment: @underloaded_operator r u suggesting to change all the other functions?

Comment: Please see [Is C/C++ one language or two languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330370/is-c-c-one-language-or-two-languages) They parted company 40 years ago! And they are *not* the same libraries. But anyway, if you are going to change the data value on a node, surely you'll have to remove and reinsert it?

Comment: @underloaded_operator I get it now!Thanks a lot!Have a good day!You can post a answer if you like I will accept it.

Comment: @Cerise I was in the same boat once with Data Structures. I'm just glad I was able to help `:)`

Comment: @WeatherVane no I will not remove and reinsert a node LOL.

Comment: Also note that you should be passing a `&` in your recursive call, so you can de-ref and update as necessary. @WeatherVane brings up a valid point if you just overwrite the data, how are you making sure your "tree" actually stays a tree?

Comment: @Cerise Usually when you are inserting a node, you implement the algorithm inside the `AddNode()`. Overwriting is fine, but you would need a helper method that will re-arrange the nodes in your "tree" and make it an actual tree.

Comment: @underloaded_operator can you please post a answer if you have the time?

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone for the free lesson on C/C++ as well

Comment: @Cerise Yeah I can, you have some other errors in your code btw...

Comment: @Cerise Interesting to note that the first C++ compilers were translators that took the C++ code and formed C code.  Then that code was compiled.  Made for interesting compiler error analysis.  So at that time, C++ could be considered a subset of C as everything in C++ was compliable in C.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that was when C++ had less capabilities than C right?

Comment: @Cerise Certainly it was less, yet I suspect most languages can translate into another with a high degree of completeness.  It is really more a question of ease to implemented certain constructs.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with "pointers-to-pointers". Here is an example of what you can do:

```c
void correctBiases (Node** node, float error) {
  if (*node == NULL) { //boilerplate
    return;
  }

  if ((*node)->leftChild == NULL && (*node)->rightChild == NULL) {
    (*node)->bias += error; //the logic
  }

  correctBiases (&((*node)->leftChild), error); // L recursive step
  correctBiases (&((*node)->rightChild), error); // R recursive step
}
```

Always implement base cases in your recursive functions (in this case you are checking for `NULL`), implement your logic, and then make your 2 recursive calls (since it's a tree).

With your recursive calls, you want to traverse the tree and potentially modify the child pointers. To do this, you need to pass the address (`&`) of the child pointers, so you can dereference and update them as necessary.

When fixing your code there were some issues, in you are not checking if the parent node is `NULL`

```c
void changeValue (Node* node, float newval)
{
  node->value = newval;
  if (node->parent != NULL) {
    node->parent->value += (node->value * node->bias);
  }
}
```

[Godbolt Example](https://godbolt.org)

Comment: Ur code only updates the values of the leafs but it was very helpful.I will study it to understand it better.

Comment: @Cerise If that's the case, then remove `if ((*node)->leftChild == NULL &&...` so you're only left with `(*node)->bias += error;`

Comment: But wait a minute!I think I have already tried your code and the compiler pops up errors.

Comment: @Cerise Click the [GodBolt link](https://godbolt.org) The errors you are getting are not from my end. I made some modifications to your code in order to make it work. Compiles with MSVC, GCC and Clang FYI. Youre the one who said you're using a C++ compiler to compile...

Comment: Hmm I think they work now that I am studying them better.

Comment: @Cerise No need to study anything, look at what the compiler outputs and the console output