# Test t=Test(); what happens in C++98?

Tags: c++, object, initialization, c++03, c++98

Consider following program:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Test
{
    int a;
};
int main()
{
    Test t=Test();
    std::cout<<t.a<<'\n';
}
```

**`Test t=Test();`** value initializes a temporary & copy initializes it. (most compilers optimize out the copy operation (Source: [**value initialization**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization))). But value initialization is introduced by `C++03`. What happens in `C++98` when **`Test t=Test();`** is executed? Is it guaranteed that I will get 0 as an output (value of `t.a` in this case) on any `C++98` compiler? . Is it default initialization being performed in `C++98`?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349679/is-value-initialization-part-of-the-c98-standard-if-not-why-was-it-added-in) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ standard (1998)

[dcl.fct.def]

> 7 An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be default-initialized.

[dcl.init]

> 5 To zero-initialize storage for an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the storage is set to the value of 0 (zero) converted to T;
>
> — if T is a non-union class type, the storage for each nonstatic data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized;
>
> — if T is a union type, the storage for its first data member 89) is zero-initialized;
>
> — if T is an array type, the storage for each element is zero-initialized;
>
> — if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.
>
> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a non-POD class type (clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>
> — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>
> — **otherwise, the storage for the object is zero-initialized.**

It appears that the temporary is default initialized, which means zero initialization for a POD type (which `Test` is) and therefore `t.a == 0` is guaranteed.

Since C++03 this is value initialization and same guarantee remains.

It appears that the addition of value initialization and re-definition of default initialization in C++03, was to allow not zero-initializing scalars and POD types (in some contexts).

Comment: and value t.a is guaranteed to be 0 since C++03. right?

Comment: @PravasiMeet I checked the definition of default initialization and rewrote the answer. It appears that the guarantee holds both pre and post C++03.