# How can I run the custom version of C++03 in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++03

For a school assignment, I am required to use C++ version 03. I have a Mac, and I was told to use Xcode by my instructor.

After a bit of research, I found the place on where to change the version of C++ that is being used. As shown in the image, the version C++03 is not available. I tried typing "C++03 [-std=c++03]" in the "Other..." option, but my build failed.

I tried searching around on here and online, but I couldn't find anything that provided a solution.

Can someone please give me some guidance on what to do here? I am entirely new to C++, and I simply just want some help in being able to compile my code.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Chose the one that says "C++98".  Or select Other... and enter `c++03`.

Comment: *I am required to use C++ version 03* Do you consider an option of changing the school or your instructor at least?

Comment: @Eljay you may turn your comment into an answer

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode on the Macintosh, to use C++03 (which should be nearly the same or identical with C++98), you can select the `C++ Language Dialect` > `Other...` > and type in `c++03` (lowercase) in the field.

C++03 was more of a "big fix" to C++98, (q.v. this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8287020/4641116)).  It resolved some ambiguities in the language specification.  Rather than being a significant new C++ standard.

You'll note that there are options like C++98 and GNU++98.  The GNU++XX options enable several GNU extensions to the language, which *if utilized* means the code will not be strictly standard C++ compliant.

C++11 was a major change to the language.  C++11 and later are sometimes referred to as "modern C++".