# syntax of initializer_list for a vector of integers

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, initializer-list

In order to understand how to use *initializer_list*, I'm writing a constructor of my own to fill a vector of integers (explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118025/brace-enclosed-initializer-list-constructor)) :

```
#include <vector>

class X
{
  std::vector< int > *vec;
public:
  X(std::initializer_list<int>);
};

X(std::initializer_list<int> values)
{
  this->vec = new std::vector<int>(values);
}
```

The line

```
X(std::initializer_list<int> values)
```

is rejected by my *g++ -std=c++11* : **invalid declarator before values.** Why ?

Comment: Try `X::X` outside the class.

Comment: `std::vector< int > *vec;` Why a pointer??

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ : you're right; of course, it was only an example.

Comment: @hellfire769 Adding an existing tag to the title is an inappropriate edit!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I didn't add the tag in the title, it was suizokukan

Comment: @hellfire769 Ah, sorry! I see you actually added the tag. Good edit action yes!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I would have removed the C++ tag (too broad audience), but that is a subjective opinion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, when you define member functions, including special member functions, outside the class definition, you must use the fully qualified name. This is necessary to indicate the function you're declaring is a member of that class, and not a free function. There are a couple of other things you should fix about your class definition.

```
class X
{
  std::vector< int > vec;
  //                ^^^     - it's unlikely this needs to be a pointer
public:
  X(std::initializer_list<int>);
};

X::X(std::initializer_list<int> values)
//^^^             - fully qualified name required
: vec(values)  // use the constructor initializer list 
               // instead of assignment within the body
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all these details, specially for the ": vec(values)" syntax I didn't know.

Comment: @suizokukan For reference, here's the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/init-lists.html) on why one should prefer using the constructor initializer list.

Answer (score 5):

As Bo Persson noticed :

```
X(std::initializer_list<int> values)
```

must be written

```
X::X(std::initializer_list<int> values)
```