# Return an array from a C++ function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, return

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473438/return-array-in-a-function) one, but not the same. That one is input array then return array. Mine is input integers, and return array.

I have an array that gets a few numbers, and makes it an array.

```
int makearr(int a, int b, int c){
    arr[2]={a,b,c};
    return?//how can I return it
}

int main(){
    //and use it?
}
```

All I want is to make the array, and display it.

Note:
Sorry, my software doesn't support tuples.

Comment: Use a `std::pair`. If you absolutely need an array, return a `std::array`. The language prohibits returning arrays from functions.

Comment: That can only return two things.

Comment: An your function takes two things. In fact, your function could be replaced with `std::make_pair`, or probably just `{a, b}` depending on where you use it.

Comment: Sorry, it's just an example. :)

Comment: pay attention, you try to return local variable.

Comment: Ok, depending on the usage, `{a, b, c}` or `std::make_tuple(a, b, c)` might be better alternatives. If an array is still the best, I suggest looking up an implementation of `make_array` so you call `make_array({a, b, c})` and get back a `std::array`.

Comment: @folibis, By value. Returning things by value is completely safe.

Comment: @chris With return-type being `std::array`, couldn't he just do `{{a,b,c,}}`?

Comment: If `std::array` and `std::tuple` are not available, there's always `boost::array` and `boost::tuple`.

Comment: you may use std::vector to return.

Comment: @Pradhan, In the function, yes, but if you're going to be turning N `int`s into a `std::array`, you might as well have a function that takes a list of arbitrary length, except my mistake, you'd probably call it like `make_array(a, b, c);`.

Comment: And yes, my suggestions are all over the map. I really have no idea what the use case of the function is, so I can't know what to focus on. For most use cases, not even calling this function and just using `{a, b, c}` is probably fine.

Comment: I'm going to call the function multiple times.

Comment: @user3875138, All of these suggestions work multiple times.

Comment: Oh! OK. Can you post an answer, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @user3875138, I still don't know exactly what you want? Could you provide a description of why you need this function and where using it will be useful?

Comment: Make the array and display it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return array in a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473438/return-array-in-a-function)

Comment: @prince it's similar, but different situation.

Comment: How is it different? The fact that you put arguments in and they use a for loop makes no difference to the answer.

Comment: @Flexo To someone who isn't all that experienced with C/++, this appears to be a slightly different situation.  Some of the comments here are unique to this question and useful.

Answer (score 4):

A `vector`?

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> makearr (T a, T b, T c)
{
    T d[] = { a, b, c };
    return std::vector<T>(d, d + 3);
}

std::vector<int> x = makearr(1, 2, 3);
// access x[i]
```

If all manner of standard containers are *verboten*, then:

```
template <typename T> struct three { T d[3]; };

template <typename T>
three<T> makearr (T a, T b, T c)
{
    three<T> d = { { a, b, c } };
    return d;
}

three<int> x = makearr(1, 2, 3);
// access x.d[i]
```

Borrowing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114299/315052) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4118050/315052), I cobbled together this C++11 solution that doesn't use standard containers:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
struct argh {
    argh (std::initializer_list<T> i) {
        std::copy_n(i.begin(), std::min(i.size(), N), v_);
    }
    T & operator [] (int i) { return v_[i]; }
    const T & operator [] (int i) const { return v_[i]; }
private:
    T v_[N];
};

template <typename T, typename... Type>
auto makearr (T&& val, Type&&... vals) -> argh<T, 1 + sizeof...(Type)>
{
    argh<T, 1 + sizeof...(Type)> arr = { val, vals... };
    return arr;
}

auto x = makearr(1, 2, 3);
// access x[i]
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm not allowed to use vectors in this mission.

Comment: What are you allowed to use?

Comment: Not vectors, not anything like a linked-list or deque.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Exactly what are you allowed to use, don't give me a list of things that I can't use that you will just add to as I use them.

Comment: @user3875138, is the array size fixed at compile time?

Comment: Is it possible to not?

Comment: There is no typesafe way to provide such a function without using C++11 features (variadic template). But, I am guessing that is a no go, since you won't allow `vector`.

Comment: Oh, OK then. Does C++11 mean any version above 11? I have Code::Blocks 13.12

Comment: C++11 refers to a version of the C++ standard that is published by the standardizing committee.

Comment: So does my version count?

Comment: @user3875138, CodeBlocks is just an IDE, not a compiler. At a guess, the compiler you're using does support C++11, at least to some degree. I think the MinGW version comes with GCC 4.7.2 or something, which supports a fair amount, and there's an option right in the compiler settings saying something like "use C++11".

Comment: Ok, how do you check what compiler it is?

Comment: @jxh, You can still hack a typesafe version into C++98. For example, Boost has a C++98 tuple. At any rate, it's not really something normal people do.

Comment: @chris: You can create a `tuple` object, but there is no real support to create a function to pack one together safely without a variadic template. A variadic function is not typesafe.

Comment: @chris: In any case, this seems silly that the OP wants to use C++11 features but not allowed to use standard containers.

Comment: @jxh, Agreed, but remember that tuples kind of require variadic templates. The variadic template is what you can hack in (via a series of `typename` parameters). It wouldn't be truly arbitrary, but it is reasonably possible.

Answer (score 1):

here nothing complex is required, you just need to return an address of your first array element to a pointer,which will ultimately display the array entries. Array must be declared globally so that it is known to ptr in `main()`.
the code is wrriten below:

```
int arr[3];   //Declare it globally
int main()
{
int *ptr;
ptr=makearr(2,4,5);
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
cout<<*ptr<<endl;
ptr++;
}
return 0;
}

int* makearr(int a,int b,int c)
{
arr[0]=a;arr[1]=b;arr[2]=c;
return(&arr[0])
}
```

Answer (score -4):

A pointer? You can store the integers in either an integer array or in an integer pointer. A function cannot return an array, however it can return a pointer.

```
int* makearr(int a, int b, int c){
int *array = new int[3];
array = &a;
array+1 = &b;
array+2 = &c;
return array;
}

int main(){
int* arr = makearr(1,2,3);
// Do something with the array. Access the elements by dereferencing the pointer variable
std::cout<<*arr<<" "<<*(arr+1);
delete arr;
return 0;
}
```

This code however has a potential memory leak if you do not delete the array pointer in your main(or wherever you invoke the makearr method from)

Comment: You want to use `array[0] = a;`

Comment: How do you display it?

Comment: And does it some what relate to arrays?

Comment: I recommend you start reading some basic material on pointers and how they work in C. All arrays can be interchangeably used with a pointer, regardless of type.

Comment: You're using the wrong `delete`. And arrays cannot be interchanged with pointers. What about `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr); ++i)` or `ArraySize(arr)` given an appropriate function template, or in `decltype(arr)` where the result should be of a specific type?

Comment: R Sahu- `array[0] = a;` and `array=&a` do the same thing

Comment: I take that as a YES?

Comment: No Sumit, they don't do the same thing. Did you even try to compile this?

Comment: @SumitChakraborty, `array[0] = a;` copies `a` to the location pointed to by `array`. `array = &a;` makes `array` point to `a` (leaking memory, and making the next two assignments that would have just done nothing into undefined behaviour).

Comment: @chris: The next two assignments don't even compile, since `array+1` is not an L-value.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, My bad, I guess I extrapolated on how you can assign to the result of a typical user-defined `operator+`.

Comment: I can count at least 3 sources of undefined behaviour here and even if the code was correct as you intended it's still not good advice.