# Why am I getting a "brace-enclosed initializer list" when the function accepts std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having issues with c++ (c++11)

this code:

```
void execute(std::vector<boost::variant<int, std::string>> params){
   printf("There are %d parameters\n", params.size());
}

execute( { 21, "test", 98 } );
```

fails with:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘execute(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118025/brace-enclosed-initializer-list-constructor

Comment: what vector accepts ints and strings without type conversion?

Comment: xaxxon if you read properly you'll see "boost::variant"

Comment: Which compiler? Which version of boost? [I can't reproduce it](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ddhhH81bfBjEAYXJ).

Comment: Do you use an **IDE**?

Comment: g++ (Debian 5.3.1-5) 5.3.1 20160101

Comment: also give the error if I use just a std::string or int without variant

Comment: I'm using sublime as my editor

Comment: @CheyenneForbesdeAvapno your code works for me. no problem. I tested it

Comment: am I supposed to be including anything?

Comment: @CheyenneForbesdeAvapno **Just** `#include <boost/variant.hpp>` and other library you use. when you want to comment someone, add **@** before its name the site warns to the person

Comment: @CheyenneForbesdeAvapno [Works for me too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd5ebff36b2fb897)