# Java-like Arrays.asList() in c++

Tags: c++, initializer-list

Does c++ support either in the STL or there exists an external library supporting [Arrays.asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))?

Typical usage

```
private ArrayList<String> lexeme = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(" ", ",", "(", ")", ";", "=", ".", "*", "-"));
```

I am using Visual Studio 11 (2012) and they have not included the c++11 feature `Initializer lists` leaving me in a quandry as to initialize a vector of nine unique strings without

```
std::vector<std::string>::push_back("a");
std::vector<std::string>::push_back("b");
std::vector<std::string>::push_back("c");
                 . . .
```

Comment: I believe this is close to your question and problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050485/implementing-a-stdarray-like-container-with-a-c11-initializer-list?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common thing to do before C++11 was to first create an array, then initialize the vector with it, for example:

```
char const * arr[] = { " ", ",", "(", ")", ";", "=", ".", "*", "-" };
std::vector<std::string> str_vec(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr));
```

Of course, VS11 does support some of C++11, so you can do this instead, which is slightly more readable:

```
char const * arr[] = { " ", ",", "(", ")", ";", "=", ".", "*", "-" };
std::vector<std::string> str_vec(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
const char* arr[] = {"a", "bc", "def"};
std::vector<std::string> vec(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

If your compiler doesn't support `std::begin()` and `std::end()`, they are easy to do without:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr));
```