# Homework: Parameters for C++ function

Tags: c++, vector

I am currently learning C++ on my own, and I face difficulty getting the parameters for my function correct.

The question and my screenshot is:

[My Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz2nj.png)

My code so far is:

```
int countInRange(Vector<int> array, int min, int max){
    /*
        Actual code goes here......
    */
    return 0;   
}
```

Right now the compiler does not accept `Vector<int> array`, and throws me this error:

`no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Vector<int>' and '<brace-enclosed initializer list>')
  param0 = {28, 1, 17, 4, 41, 9, 59, 8, 31, 30, 25};`

I understand that this question is using a Stanford standard library, but I don't think that is the main problem.

I would appreciate any help on fixing the `Vector<int> array` part. Thank you!

Thanks for the help guys! I understand that the standard library "std::vector" might be different from Stanford's library "Vector" with capital "V":

http://stanford.edu/~stepp/cppdoc/Vector-class.html

I will try to provide more information to help everyone.

Comment: `Vector` should be `vector` (All small letters) if from `std`

Comment: Could you show the declaration of param0? I am guessing it is a Vector<int> and therefore the assignment youre attempting is invalid.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't think the question in the external link is important at all. We are not here to do your homework so we don't really care about what the assignment is. We are here to answer 1 specific question about a problem you are having with your implementation. What is important is presenting enough code to reproduce the error message. Right now you have not done that so your question is not answerable.

Comment: Are you compililing with -std=c++11 ?

Comment: What happen when the vector is a const&: Vector<int> const& array?

Comment: Your external screenshot (usually frowned upon) does not match your error message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Right now because I don't know the implementation by the Stanford professor (e.g. param0, C++11, etc), I will take your question and ask him/her directly.

Answer (score 3):

The "main problem" is the use of the Stanford standard library which does not define a *initializer list* constructor for the template class [Vector](http://stanford.edu/~stepp/cppdoc/Vector-class.html).

Use maybe the [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/), which has a *initializer list* constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a homework assignment, I won't do the work for you, but I'll give you some directions. I'm sure you understand; at the end of the day, you need to understand what you will end up delivering.

What your compiler error tells you is that you cannot initialize your Stanford Vector instance in the way you tried putting the numbers in there; such a way is impossible, you will have to do it another way. So,

```
param0 = {28, 1, 17, 4, 41, 9, 59, 8, 31, 30, 25}; //not possible
```

as such, you will have to use other methods to get your added to the Stanford Vector. you can investigate:

- the vector functions "add" and "push_back"
- the vector initilization method `vector<t> name(values)`
- the vector function "insert"

Or, as others suggested, you can switch over to std::vector instead of the Stanford Vector. However, do make sure that is in line with your assignment requirements

Answer (score -2):

You are probably not assigning values to the Vector correctly. This can help you a bit.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3424937/1606281